# Rewrite rule .htaccess for my sitemap.xml

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, url-rewrite-module

I have a content management system plugin installed that provides a sitemap for Google under http://www.domain.com/index.php?eID=dd_googlesitemap how can I add a rewrite rule to my .htaccess that will make this sitemap available under http://www.domain.com/sitemap.xml instead?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can add this code to your htaccess file (which has to be in root folder)

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^sitemap\.xml$ /index.php?eID=dd_googlesitemap [L]
```

Make sure `mod_rewrite` is enabled